# JavaFX - Bind LocalTime to TableColumn via Property

Tags: java, javafx, properties, observable, localtime

I am using JavaFX to wrap existing classes with properties, so that I may bind them to a GUI directly without having to manually hook up events. Here is a sample of my code:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import controller.NewOrder;
import controller.Types.Action;

public class ObservableOrder extends NewOrder
{
    private StringProperty m_account;
    private ObjectProperty<Action> m_action;

    public ObservableOrder()
    {
        // CONSTRUCT PROPERTIES
        m_account = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "m_account");
        m_action  = new SimpleObjectProperty<Action>(this, "m_action", Action.BUY);
    }

    // GETTERS
    @Override public String account() { return m_account.get(); }
    @Override public Action action() { return m_action.get(); }

    // SETTERS
    @Override public void account(String v) { accountProperty().set(v); }
    @Override public void action(Action v) { actionProperty().set(v); }

    // PROPERTY GETTERS
    public StringProperty accountProperty() { return m_account; }
    public ObjectProperty<Action> actionProperty() { return m_action; }
}
```

This works for integers, strings and enums. What I would like to do next is wrap a LocalTime object with properties and bind it to a table column, but I can't figure it out. Should I use ObservableValue instead? Any help is appreciated. Thx

Comment: So what is the question? What did you try to do, and why isn't it working?

Comment: The question is how do I bind a LocalTime to a TableColumn?

Comment: With an `ObjectProperty<LocalTime>`, and a `TableColumn<NewOrder, LocalTime>` ?

Comment: A little embarassed right now, thanks :)